# android GET_ACCOUNTS permission

Tags: android, permissions

What exactly the GET_ACCOUNTS permission on anroid can give me?

I see all the emails that are connected to a device?
do I see also the facebook acounts or UIDs that are connected to an acount?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can get all accounts registered on device, not only google:

```
try {
            Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();
            for (Account account : accounts) {
                Item item = new Item( account.type, account.name);
                accountsList.add(item);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception", e);
        }
```

Comment: The question is what GET_ACCOUNTS permission provides?? @Nick Titov

Comment: Provides an ability to get all accounts from device.